# How to create Event Handler for MessageBox OK button? (C#)

Tags: events, button, handler, message

When the user will click the "OK" button on the MessageBox below, something will happen for example, it will clear out the searchResult string and set it to "". Just to clarify, a message box will open up and show some string message (searchResult), but as soon as the user clicks on "OK" on that message box, searchResult will be set to "". How can I achieve this? How to create an event handler for this particular message box's OK button?

```
if (searchResult != "")
{
     MessageBox.Show(searchResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a listener. Just set `searchResult` to an empty string right after calling `MessageBox.Show`:

```
if (searchResult != "")
{
     MessageBox.Show(searchResult);
     searchResult = "";
}
```

Comment: that causes some problems in terms of functionality with the rest of my program.

Comment: Please be more specific. `MessageBox.Show` should block current thread until the user closes the message box (clicks OK or otherwise). So it should do the exact thing you want.

Comment: nevermind guys. moved it into backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you are interested :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx